# Как создать две таблицы в SAS из одной базы данных

Tags: sql, sas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать две таблицы в SAS из одной базы данных. Заранее благодарю.

Вопрос (в переводе) звучит так: Создайте набор, содержащий все переменные инцидента  ANGINA, HOSPMI, HYPERTEN, MI_FCHD, STROKE. Создайте сумму, которая включает в себя инциденты. Условно выведите данные в две разные таблицы SAS: один, у которого есть предметы с 1 или более инцидентами, и один с субъектами без инцидентов.

В оригинале: Create a set that contains all incident variables (non-cumulative cases): ANGINA, HOSPMI, HYPERTEN, MI_FCHD, STROKE. Create a sum that includes incidents. Conditionally output the data to two different SAS tables: one that has subjects with 1 or more incidents and one with subjects with no incidents.

По какому принципу суммировать данные, чтобы из них вывести две таблицы: "без инцидентов" и "1 и более инц."
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение без SQL на SAS Base:

```
data testData;
    array colNames [*] ANGINA HOSPMI HYPERTEN MI_FCHD STROKE;
    do subjectId = 1 to 1000;
        do i = 1 to dim(colNames);
            colNames[i] = round(rand("uniform"))*round(rand("uniform")*3);
        end;
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;

data noIncedents incedents;
    set testData;
    array incedentTypes {*} ANGINA HOSPMI HYPERTEN MI_FCHD STROKE;

    totalIncedents = 0;
    do currentIncedent = 1 to dim(incedentTypes);   
        totalIncedents = totalIncedents + incedentTypes[currentIncedent];       
    end;

    if totalIncedents >=1 then do;
        output incedents;
    end;
    else do;
        output noIncedents;
    end;
    drop currentIncedent;
run;
```